# Install qiskit in django project

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I was wondering if it's possible to use qiskit inside a django project. I found some ways to install jupyter notebooks, but I am not sure what is happening with qiskit.
Ideally I would like to import and use qiskit to a web app with a very simple user interface. I haven't found anything similar.
Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Qiskit is simply a python library so you can use it in the same way you would use any other python library in a Django project.

I am not sure how you would envision the user interface, but you could always use some kind of text input to allow the user to write code, have it execute on the backend and then pass the results back.